# Can't connect to mysql pod in Kubernetes when using Secrets for password (Access denied)

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

I try to setup a mysql database in Kubernetes. I configured a ConfigMap to store the Database name and a Secret that contains the root password, the user and the password for the user.

When I try to connect to the DB afterwards (Inside the container with mysql cli and from outside with IntelliJ Database tool) I get an "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testadm'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" error.

My kubernetes.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db
data:
  mysql-database: database

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: db-credentials
type: Opaque
data:
  mysql-root-password: VGVzdDEyMzQK # Test1234
  mysql-user: dGVzdGFkbQo= # testadm
  mysql-password: VGVzdDEyMzQK # Test1234

---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:5.7
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db
                  key: mysql-database
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-credentials
                  key: mysql-root-password
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-credentials
                  key: mysql-user
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-credentials
                  key: mysql-password
```

**If I set the passwords directly like below the connection succeeds** inside of the container and from the outside!

```
env:
  - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    value: Test1234
```

If I inspect the env variables inside the container I can't spot a difference between the two approaches.

Is there any additional formatting required to use the passwords stored in the secret? I also tried to place the values in the data-dictionary in quotes like this:

```
data:
  mysql-root-password: "VGVzdDEyMzQK"
```

Version information

```
Docker 17.06.0-ce
Minikube 0.21.0
Kubectl Server 1.7.0
Kubectl Client 1.7.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: db-credentials
type: Opaque
data:
  mysql-password: VGVzdDEyMzQ=
  mysql-root-password: VGVzdDEyMzQ=
  mysql-user: dGVzdGFkbQ==
```

Comment: Not working. Still same error.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the data in your secret yaml is base64-encoded correctly? Using https://www.base64encode.org/, your `data` block is supposed to look like:

```
data:
  mysql-root-password: VGVzdDEyMzQ= # Test1234
  mysql-user: dGVzdGFkbQ== # testadm
  mysql-password: VGVzdDEyMzQ= # Test1234
```

Comment: Yes, I did it like it is described in the documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-manually - On my machine "echo Test1234 | base64" results in VGVzdDEyMzQK.

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake now. I forgot the -n flag. Thanks!

Comment: @SteffenSchmitz, can you provide more details about the -n flag? I am facing the same problem here. Thanks.

Comment: @KokHowTeh Without the -n flag echo adds a new line to the end of the string and also encodes it. Your password usually shouldn’t have line breaks inside and that is why the flag is required.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having an issue not resolved by line breaks issue as was case with OP here, note that you can't change the mysql password once the database is created. The environment variable is only read when the db is created so if you are using a persistent volume claim you need log in with the old password and change it "manually": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the access to client machine to connect mysql database.

replace the `<ip>` address with your desktop ip and run this command on mysql database. then test the connection.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'<ip>'   WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'   WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The way you created secret is not correct. remove and create it like this.  I tested in my cluster it worked.

```
kubectl create secret generic db-credentials --from-literal=mysql-root-password=Test1234 --from-literal=mysql-user=testadm --from-literal=mysql-password=Test1234
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem. The access is also refused when I try it inside of the container. It also only happens when I use the password configured in my K8S secret and not when I configure the env directly.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too. Is there any way to create the secret from a yaml file?

Comment: added the yaml file, test it.

Comment: @sfgroups, I am facing the same issue here. How to configure the GRANT from kubernetes manifest yaml file? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think its good idea add grant command in yaml file. you need to run this one time, login to the pod using `kubectl exec ` command and grant the permission.

Answer (score -1):

Following worked me by having the db password as `stringData`.

[image]

**Secret:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  db: bG8ryXYx1cw==
  db_username: cm9vdA==

stringData:
  app_port: '3000'
  db_host: 'db-sql.default.svc.cluster.local'
  db_port: '3306'
  db_password: ‘<redacted>!'
```

In your `Deployment` yaml

```
 - name: DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: lokalus-server-secret
                key: db_password
```