# Kubernetes mysql 8.0.13 do not initialize properly from ENV

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, containers, access-denied

I am using mysql 8.0.13 from docker hub registry. I am not able to connect to the database from within the pod shell. However, I am able to do so when running the docker container on my localhost without using kubernetes. With reference to [Can't connect to mysql pod in Kubernetes when using Secrets for password (Access denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650044/cant-connect-to-mysql-pod-in-kubernetes-when-using-secrets-for-password-access), I have tried both setting the root password value inside the manifest and using k8s secret but to no avail. I can't connect to it remotely but I can connect to a local container with the same image remotely. Even setting MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD doesn't work but it works on localhost container without kubernetes.

```
khteh@khteh-T580:~ 2035 $ k exec -it mysql-0 -- bash
root@mysql-0:/# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@mysql-0:/# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@mysql-0:/# mysql -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@mysql-0:/# mysql -p""
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@mysql-0:/# echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

root@mysql-0:/# 
$ k exec -it mysql-0 -- bash
root@mysql-0:/# mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@mysql-0:/# echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
<snip>
root@mysql-0:/# mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'iconverse'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@mysql-0:/# echo $MYSQL_PASSWORD
<snip>
root@mysql-0:/# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.13 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
root@mysql-0:/#
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your deployment for mysql?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Please share the .yaml files which you used to deploy the mysql pod.

Comment: I have left the office. I will provide the yml tomorrow.

Comment: I restarted my kubernetes cluster and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before and not sure why one can't login to MySQL when pod is created. Restarted cluster should solve the issue.